# PHP creating 500 Error

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with a function I've gotten for displaying all of the Files and sub-directory files of a given directory. It works locally, but when I upload it, the page just gives a 500 Error.

I have tried chmod'ing to 777, even the entire directory that it searches, but nothing seems to work. Any help is appreciated!

```
<?php

$directory = '../..';
$files = listFiles($directory, 'start.js');

echo json_encode($files);

function listFiles($dir, $origin) {
    $directory = scandir($dir);
    $files = [];

    foreach($directory as $file){
        if($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
            $thisFile = $dir . '/' . $file;

            if(is_dir($thisFile)) {
                $files = array_merge($files, listFiles($thisFile, $origin));
            }else{
                $tempDir = str_replace('../..', '/game', $thisFile);
                $extension = substr(strrchr($thisFile, '.'), 1);

                if($extension == 'js' && strpos($thisFile, $origin) === false) $files[] = $tempDir;
            }
        }
    }

    return $files;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if you have error reporting enabled on the server?

Comment: What has chmod to do with an 500 error? Anyway, mostly a 500 error is caused by apache. Did you change anything in the `.htaccess`?

Comment: @BenM Yes, and I've tried using `ini_set` and `error_reporting` to enable error messages, but still 500 error

Comment: If you're hosting on a shared server, the chmod to 777 may be your issue. Many shared hosts are configured to give 500 errors if the files/directories are group and/or global writeable. Try setting all files to 644 and all directories to 755.

Comment: @dleiftah It's not on shared hosting, but I'll give that a go.

Comment: Can you look into PHP error log and tell what it says?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax:

```
$files = [];
```

Is only available from a certain PHP version (5.4 I think). Check that the server has the same version as your development environment.

Answer (score 2):

First enable error reporting using the following PHP code:

```
 ini_set('display_errors','On');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Second, check for syntax errors or something else.
Like previous commenters said the syntax..

```
$files = [];
```

..is only available from a certain PHP version (5.4 I think). Check that the server has the same version as your development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on my localhost:

```
<?php

    $directory = '../..';
    $files = listFiles($directory, 'start.js');

    echo json_encode($files);

    function listFiles($dir, $origin) {
        $directory = scandir($dir);
        $files = array();

        foreach($directory as $file){
            if($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
                $thisFile = $dir . '/' . $file;

                if(is_dir($thisFile)) {
                    $files = array_merge($files, listFiles($thisFile, $origin));
                }else{
                    $tempDir = str_replace('../..', '/game', $thisFile);
                    $extension = substr(strrchr($thisFile, '.'), 1);

                    if($extension == 'js' && strpos($thisFile, $origin) === false) $files[] = $tempDir;
                }
            }
        }

        return $files;
    }
```

PS: First the code fives me an error on $files var...i change that and it works.